# How to i programatically change the page thats loaded from hook_init?

Tags: nodes, hooks

I am in the process of building a drupal module that will block access to certain IP addresses, i've built the whole thing and it works a treat except from one area of functionality; i would like to be able to redirect blocked users to a node.

The code that i have does everything except display the node:

```
if (variable_get('lock_denied_response_type') == 2){
  $node_id = variable_get('lock_denied_node');
  $node = node_load($node_id);
  $node_view = node_view($node, FALSE, TRUE);
  drupal_render_page($node_view);
  exit;
}
else{
  echo variable_get('lock_denied_html');
  exit;
}
```

I've scanned google, stack overflow etc but not much luck. So far as i can tell, it appears my approach is wrong and rather than triggering my own render page, i should just change which node the standard rendering process uses, something like this:

```
if (variable_get('lock_denied_response_type') == 2){
  $node_id = variable_get('lock_denied_node');
  /* insert awesome node override code here */
}
else{
  echo variable_get('lock_denied_html');
  exit;
}
```

Suggestions?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do somthing like this:

```
function MY_MODULE_init() {
    global $user;

    // or you can also use ip_address() function
    if($user->hostname == 'MY_BLOCKED_IP') {
      drupal_goto('node/NID_OF_IP_BLOCKED_NODE');
    }
  }
```

2-aproach (this is a recommended way. Because hook_init() will be removed from drupal v8):

```
// in template.php
function MY_THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if($variables['user']->hostname == 'BLOCKED_IP') {
    drupal_goto('node/NID_OF_IP_BLOCKED_NODE');
  }
}
```

Comment: awesome, the node/ bit was the winner difference between two great answers :) thanks!

Comment: @misterkoz See my updated answer. I showed a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

[httpbl](https://drupal.org/project/httpbl) has a similar concept and it seems that it's using [hook_boot](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_boot/7).

So you might have something similar to:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_boot()
 */
function example_boot() {
  $result = example_check_ip(); // Check IP immediately upon access
  if ($result) {
    if ($_GET['q'] == '<URL_TO_NODE_YOU_WANT_TO_DISPLAY_IF_IP_IS_BLOCKED') {
      return;
    }

    drupal_goto('<URL_TO_NODE_YOU_WANT_TO_DISPLAY_IF_IP_IS_BLOCKED');
  }
}
```